# Rename generated files in Makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have to modify a Makefile such that the intermediate files with extension `.cc` are moved to `.cpp` before building the `.o.` files. My modified Makefile looks like below.

```
PROTOC=protoc
all: client_grpc pb

client_grpc: abc.pb.o abc.grpc.pb.o client_grpc.o
  $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

pb: %.pb.cc
  mv $^ $@ 

%.grpc.pb.cc: %.proto
  $(PROTOC) --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH) $<

%.pb.cc: %.proto
  $(PROTOC) --cpp_out=. $<

clean:
  rm -f *.o *.pb.cc *.pb.h client_gqegrpc
```

`protoc` is a compiler that generates `.cc` files. How to make targets so that after generating the `.cc` files those are move to `.cpp` and then the `client_grpc` is built using the `.cpp` files ?

Comment: Just curious, if there any particular reason why you have to rename the .cc files to .cpp files? You could just compile .cc files directly into .o files, as long as the former is real c++ code.

Comment: There is another tool that identifies .cpp files only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do this would be to have your rule produce .cpp files:

```
%.pb.cpp: %.proto
        $(PROTOC) --cpp_out=. $<
        mv $*.pb.cc $*.pb.cpp
```