# gnatmake -o flag produces incorrect object file name

Tags: gcc, ada, gnat, ghdl

I am attempting to compile a `.adb` file with `gnatmake`, and the `-o` flag isn't producing the object file name I want:

```
$ gnatmake --GCC=g++ -D bin/src/ghdl_grt/ -f -u -c src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb -o bin/src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb.o

g++ -c -Isrc/ghdl_grt/ -I- -o /home/jon/controlix-code/bin/src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.o src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb
```

As you can see, it gets the path correct, but the filename should end with `.adb.o` and it only ends with `.o`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have no choice but to use Ada on this project, since GHDL is the only open-source VHDL compiler/simulator I can find, I need to support VHDL in the embedded system I'm putting together for this project, and I need to use GNAT since it is alto the only game in town....

Comment: Why do you need ".adb.o" ?

Comment: I need the ".adb.o" thing to calculate recursive dependencies in the makefile system I'm using.

Comment: UPDATE:  I found out how to use "mv" to rename with wildcards from within the makefile (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523099/rename-generated-files-in-makefile), which seems to have fixed my problem.  I still think it is wierd for GNAT to have a "-o" option which (silently) changes the name of the output file while leaving the output _directory_ unchanged(?!??).  Confusing to say the least....

Comment: @JonTaylor -- It is kind of weird, but then GCC is, at this point, rather crufty and has all sorts of... accumulations and idiosyncrasies

Answer (score 6):

For gnatmake, -o 'chooses an alternate *executable* name'. But even using gcc (or g++) on its own fails, at any rate on macOS, because `gnat1: incorrect object file name`.

I found that you can compile to assembler and then compile that. Using a local file I happened to have lying about,

```
$ g++ -D $PWD -c gator2.adb -S -o gator2.adb.s
$ g++ -D $PWD -c gator2.adb.s
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's a weird naming scheme, but...
`gnatmake` only allows you to specify alternate **executable** names with `-o`:

> -o name  Choose an alternate executable name

You can, however, tell gnatmake to pass on options to the compiler:

> -cargs opts   opts are passed to the compiler

And similarly, to the binder and linker:

> -bargs opts   opts are passed to the binder
>
> -largs opts   opts are passed to the linker

Thus,

```
$ gnatmake --GCC=g++ -D bin/src/ghdl_grt/ -f -u -c src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb -cargs -o bin/src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb.o
```

Comment: The above solution isn't working: "gnatmake --GCC=g++ -D bin/src/ghdl_grt/ -f -u -c src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb -cargs -o bin/src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb.o" produces this output: "g++ -c -Isrc/ghdl_grt/ -o bin/src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb.o -I- -o /home/jon/controlix-code/bin/src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.o src/ghdl_grt/grt-vstrings_io.adb", which leads to an error (presumably due to the presence of multiple different -o switches and arguments)....